# How to get current record ID using N/currentRecord module?

Tags: suitescript2.0

I've tried researching and done some testing and I can't make it work below is the code im using

```
var currentRecordObj = currentRecord.get();
        var internalId = currentRecordObj.id;
        log.debug('Internal ID of the current record:', internalId);
```

I'm trying to log the record ID of my current record using SS2.X

Comment: The code you provided should work in a ClientScript. Could you please then show the whole script ? Looks like either errors appear in your case, or the module hasn't been loaded at all

Comment: Hi @d.k Thank you for insights. So this new thread is related to my previous thread. I think it would be better if I mention what I'm trying to achieve. 

I'm creating a script to create a button in the Sales Invoice page that when clicked it will transform the sales invoice into a Credit Note. 

the goal is very simple but I'm having so much difficulty in achieving it iether workflow or SS2.X. Looking for your insights. Thank you so much

Comment: So could you please share the ClientScript code? I guess it's loaded and run, since you received a reference error in it, but I'm not sure. As I said, the code you provided seems to be correct. So the reason why it doesn't work must be elsewhere, not in that provided snippet.

Comment: Hi @d.k thanks for responding back. I was able to make it work now. Thank you!

Comment: You should post an answer here. It will earn you some points and will help others with similar problems

Comment: Great idea thanks @d.k.  So I was able to fix my error because I was able to findthis in the NS help that alternatively if using client script and pageinit function. we can use context

so to fix my code I did the below code
`var currentRecord = context.currentRecord.id` and I was able to retrieve the current Record ID I'm in.